# How to access to Looker Studio API?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-oauth, looker-studio, looker

I want to add or delete user permissions for the looker studio dashboard using python,
but I'm having trouble with the authentication process.

I tried to get access token for Looker Studio API with service account or OAuth2 client,
but there's always permission denied error.

```py
iat = int(time.time())
exp = iat + 3600

claim_set = {
    "iss": service_account["client_email"],
    "scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/datastudio",
    "aud": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token", "exp": exp, "iat": iat}

encoded = jwt.encode(claim_set, service_account["private_key"], algorithm="RS256")
params = {"grant_type": "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer", "assertion": encoded}
response = requests.post("https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token", params=params)

access_token = response.json()["access_token"]

headers = {"Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}", "Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}
url = f"https://datastudio.googleapis.com/v1/assets/{assetName}/permissions"
permissions = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
permissions.text
```

I used above python code to access to looker studio API.
`service_account` is the json key object.

It returns
`{'error': {'code': 403, 'message': 'The caller does not have permission', 'status': 'PERMISSION_DENIED'}}`

Secondary, I tried to use OAuth2 client,
but every time logged in google, `Error 400: invalid_scope` occurred.

I think it might be that I didn't add the scope "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/datastudio"
from OAuth consent screen, however I cound't to that, even if I did enable Looker Studio API.

I tried to gather additional information through web searches,
but I couldn't find a solution or other method, so I'm asking here.

I consequently need permission to make HTTP requests in the reference,
https://developers.google.com/looker-studio/integrate/api/reference/permissions/addMembers